# Detecting Weather a Dom Element is a Child of Another Dom Element in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

The use case I have is disabling button interactions that aren't inside of my modal, My Plan is to detect weather or not that Btn that was clicked or Used is inside or outside the Modal.

My current implementation is "extra" Instead of having to set Classes and Remove them it would be easier for me to just detect weather or not elements are under that specific element.

```
 this.btnList = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('button');
 this.renderer.addClass(this.btnList, 'outsideModal');


  this.renderer.removeClass(this.btnList, 'outsideModal');
```

Using:

```
private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRe
```

How do I detect if a button element which is being passed in like this:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
    keyDownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
```

Is inside of:

```
<div class="modal"><!--Child Elements with Button here!></div>
```

Comment: you can maybe call different function for buttons which are inside modal so that way you know where the button was clicked

Comment: The issue is the Buttons are extremely Dynamic, So I might not always know which Button is where, For instance Button A might be on Modal A-B but not on Modal C.